# How do deserialize an entire response that could be an array or a single object?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a situation where the response from an API can contain either an array or a single item. However, I'm struggling with the deserialization of the responses due to the array response containing another nested object. Here are the different responses that can be returned (sample).

This is the format of the response when a list of items is returned

```
{
  "data": {
    "items": [
       {
          "id": 1
       },
       {
          "id": 2
       }
    ]
  }
}
```

This is the response that gets sent when a single item is returned

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

My initial attempt to standardize the response included creating a custom converter attribute, but the issue there is you cannot pass a generic parameter into it. The code for the ReadJson is below:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
    if(token["items"]?.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
        return token["items"].ToObject<T>();
    }

    return new List<T>() { token.ToObject<T>() };
}
```

Here is the class that represents a response, but I'm getting the error that generics cannot be pass into attributes. After reading into it further, it seems as though this is by design.

```
public  class Response<T>
{
    [JsonProperty("version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(SingleOrArrayConverter<T>)]
    public T Data { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("_links")]
    public Links Links { get; set; }
}
```

Anyone have any other thoughts/solutions to this problem?

Comment: Making the response consistent will simplify things.  Always return an array, even if there's only 1 element.

Comment: You could create two responses, one with an array and one with a single object. Deserialize to a `dynamic` object first and check if the object is an array or not, then deserialize to the appropriate class.

Comment: What is generic about the response? Both have a similarity in the fact that it's `"id" : <integer>` - the only difference is if `JToken["items"]` exists or not

Comment: hmmm he didn't wrote that the real problem is `[JsonConverter(SingleOrArrayConverter<T>)]` ... **he already solve inconsistent object**

Comment: instead `ToObject<T>()` you can use `ToObject(Type)` ... you have to change  `public T Data` to  `public List<T> Data` ... you can obtain `T` from `objectType`

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GxFJ6a

Comment: Yeah I agree with archer, why are you making an API that doesn't have a consistent return type.  Why don't you just make 2 endpoints?

Comment: I unfortunately don't have control over the API as it's a third party providing the responses. @Selvin thanks for the example. This looks like more of what I need.

Comment: @Selvin I think you have proposed a good solution; it would be great if you could add it as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Have a few classes like below:

```
        public class Response
        {
            [JsonProperty("data")]
            public Data ResponseData { get; set; }
        }
        public class Data
        {
            [JsonProperty("id",NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
            public long? Id { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("items", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
            public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
        }
        public class Item
        {
            public long? Id { get; set; }
        }
```

Then Deserialize the response like below:

```
var responseObject = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(responseString);
```

To further improve accessing the elements of data, include the below property to the Data class:

```
public List<Item> ResponseItems
            => Id != null
            ? new List<Item>(new Item[] { new Item { Id = Id} })
            : Items;
```